# Get value from "select" option doesn't work after implementing Boostrap "data-live-search=true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to create a dropdown with search field using Bootstrap.

I set

```
data-live-search="true"
```

to enable the search field.

Everything works fine, but I need to get the input value through JS because i need use the for an AJAX call. Before using data-live-search it was working but now it's not working anymore. I think because Boostrap changed my code.

Here is my dropdown

```
<select name="market" id="market" class="market selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="USDT-BTC">USDT-BTC</option>
    <option value="USDT-ETH">USDT-ETH</option>
    <option value="USDT-LTC">USDT-LTC</option>
    <option value="USDT-BCC">USDT-BCC</option>
    <option value="USDT-DASH">USDT-DASH</option>
    <option value="USDT-BTG">USDT-BTG</option>
    <option value="USDT-ETC">USDT-ETC</option>
    <option value="USDT-ZEC">USDT-ZEC</option>
    <option value="USDT-XMR">USDT-XMR</option>
    <option value="BTC-ADA">BTC-ADA</option>
    <option value="BTC-ETH">BTC-ETH</option>
    <option value="BTC-XRP">BTC-XRP</option>
    <option value="BTC-SC">BTC-SC</option>
</select>
```

And here is my JS code

```
$(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});

setInterval(function () {
    var url = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>;
    var valuereq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var thisMarket = document.getElementById("market"); //select element
    var market = thisMarket.value; //i get the value from the option field
    valuereq.open("GET", url+'?market='+market, true); 
    valuereq.send();
    valuereq.status;
    valuereq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (valuereq.readyState == 4 && valuereq.status == 200) {
            var return_data = valuereq.responseText;
            document.getElementById("AJAXMoneta").innerHTML = "Actual value "+market + " :" + return_data;
        }
        else document.getElementById("AJAXMoneta").innerHTML = "Error"; 
    }
}, 1400);
```

Is there a reason why javascript can't get the value from the element anymore?
Is there a way to solve?

Comment: Try using the "selectedIndex" property on the select variable, this will return the index of which option is selected, and you can then use this to get the correct option value.

Comment: I didn't know that DOM property thank you very much for teaching me.